# my activity close when i receive sms

Tags: java, android-studio

when I receive SMS my current activity close and don't know why, I just refresh my listview with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged. when I send message I can refresh it, it just work but not when I receive

here is my Broadcast Receiver

```
    public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String from;
    String msg;
    long time;
    PrintMessage pm = new PrintMessage();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        abortBroadcast();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                // Convertir les PDUs en messages
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }

            // Enfin, traiter les messages
            for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                from = message.getOriginatingAddress();
                msg = message.getMessageBody();
                time = message.getTimestampMillis();
            }
        }
       pm.printMessage();
    }
}
```

then my code where i display message

```
    public class PrintMessage extends AppCompatActivity implements Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns {

    String idPerso, numero, contact, msg, from;
    long time;
    Intent intent;
    ArrayList<CreateMessageAdapter> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ImageButton buttonSend;
    EditText textSMS;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    MessageAdapter adapter;
    String[] selection;
    Cursor cursor;
    TextView tv_toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_print_message);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_messa);
        buttonSend = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Et_message);
        tv_toolbar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_toolbar);

        intent = getIntent();
        idPerso = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        numero = intent.getStringExtra("numero");
        contact = intent.getStringExtra("contact");

        selection = new String[]{
                Telephony.Sms.THREAD_ID,
                Telephony.Sms.BODY,
                Telephony.Sms.TYPE,
                Telephony.Sms.DATE,
                Telephony.Sms.DATE_SENT,
        };

        printMessage();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (!contact.equals("no"))
            tv_toolbar.setText(contact);
        else
            tv_toolbar.setText(numero);
        tv_toolbar.setMaxWidth(550);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //enlever le titre originel

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();
                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(numero, null, sms, null, null);
                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
//                    Cursor cTmp = cr.query(uri, selection, Telephony.Sms.THREAD_ID + "='" + idPerso + "'", null, "date ASC");
//                    cTmp.moveToFirst();
//                    int typeTmp = cTmp.getInt(2);
                    list.add(new CreateMessageAdapter(2, sms, time));
                    textSMS.setText("");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void printMessage() {
        // Read stored sms
        Uri uri = Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI;
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        cursor = cr.query(uri, selection, Telephony.Sms.THREAD_ID + "='" + idPerso + "'", null, "date ASC");
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            int type = cursor.getInt(2);
            String body = cursor.getString(1);
            long dateNumber = cursor.getLong(3);
            long dateNumberSent = cursor.getLong(4);
            if (type == 2)
                list.add(new CreateMessageAdapter(type, body, dateNumber));
            else if (type == 1 || type == 5 || type == 6)
                list.add(new CreateMessageAdapter(type, body, dateNumberSent));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        adapter = new MessageAdapter(list, this);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_message);
        lv.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        lv.setStackFromBottom(true);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(PrintMessage.this, "long clicked pos: " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(final ContextMenu menu, final View v, final ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: well no it gives me this error 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.ducha.training3.MessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference', why it is null ??? i added something :/  @Sam

Answer (score 0):

replace `adapter = new MessageAdapter(list, this);`

with `adapter = new MessageAdapter(list, PrintMessage.this);`

in `printMessage()`

Comment: already try. but in my refresh method when I use my adapter like, this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged, my adapter is null and i think that's why it's not working but i don't know how to resolve that

Comment: well the problem is that when I try to get my adapter, it's always NULL, so can't refresh it, I tried to create an another one (Exception too), tried to update it in my BroadcasReceiver (PrintMessage.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged) always NULL

Comment: just call adapter.notfynotifyDataSetChanged no need for PrintMessage.adapter

Comment: ok but the adapter is in the PrintMessage class, so i can't access it without using an instance of PrintMessage